# Nuget package has 'restore packages on build' , what has bower, grunt or node

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, nuget, bower

I have the `bower_components` (8MB) in my client\app folder.
I have the `node_modules` folder (72MB) in client folder.

My free subversion hosting is just 50 MB. That should be normally not a problem not uploading binaries, packages etc... just the source code.

Just like with nuget packages I do not commit them to subversion. Because they cost too much space. But nuget package manager offers a feature called 'restore nuget packages on build' When this feature is enabled in my Visual Studio a `.nuget.exe` is created (1,5MB) This .exe file I do commit to make it available to other devs that they can also restore the nuget package when they rebuild the solution they downloaded.

Is there a similar mechanism for `bower_components` and `node_modules`?

I mean there is the `package.json` for the `node_modules` and the `bower_components` has the `bower.json` one level up in the folder structure.

Should it not be possible somehow when some else check out my source code from subversion (no `node_modules` or `bower_components` just the .json files) that a mechanism like maybe grunt is running a restore task for `node_modules` and `bower_components`

Is that somehow possible or does there already exist a solution in front of me :P ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They would just need to run `npm install` and `bower install` in their terminal to get the files.